# What are these long gold plated SMD components on the NVidia Tesla A100?

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

This photo shows a NVIDIA Tesla A100 board. Please note the 4 SMD components on each side of the chip. Looks like gold plated ceramics. I have never seen components like this. Can someone identify this components?

[image]

Link to full story:
https://www.guru3d.com/news-story/nvidia-tesla-a100-with-ga100-ampere-gpu-spotted.html

Comment: Most likely custom voltage regulation modules.

Comment: also, this, and all images on the site you link to are just 3D renderings, and might or might not look like the real device, at all.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this is a [*Power-On-Package* from Vicor](http://powerblog.vicorpower.com/2017/08/power-package-higher-performance-artificial-intelligence/).

They call these *modular current multiplieres (MCM)* and they are basically step down converters. They aim to drive these with their *modular current drivers (MCD)* with a voltage of up to 48V from the mainboard and step the voltage down only a few cm from the current hungry IC (that might draw up to 640A peak\$^1\$), to reduce power losses in PCB traces and socket pins.

On [this page](http://powerblog.vicorpower.com/2018/10/powering-growth-ai-processing/) they say that NVidia uses these modules for the AI accelerators.

\$^1:\$ *Disclaimer: Marketing data*

[image]

[image]
*Image source: [Vicor Website](http://powerblog.vicorpower.com/2017/08/power-package-higher-performance-artificial-intelligence/)*